# is there a way to cast to any type in template angular

Tags: angular

I am using angular to draw some table.

Each table as an object with some property, and when using cdk-table, the type element is any;

```
<ng-container [cdkColumnDef]="'myColumn'">
  <th class="w-20 text-left" cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>
    myColumn
  </th>
  <td class="text-left" cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let element">
    element here is of type any
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

I know we can make some casting type pipe like

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'cast',
  pure: true
})
export class CastPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor() {
  }

  transform(value: any, args?: any): Event {
    return value;
  }
}
```

but it would require to make a pipe for each table in my app.

I was wondering if there is a way to do a generic casting pipe that we can for exemple assign like this

`*cdkCellDef="let element | cast:MyInterface"`

I tried to get this interface type, but it never compile saying I can't do this.

Comment: `interfaces` in typescript are removed once `ts` code is transpilled into `js` .

Comment: I don't understand your answer, I am not talking about js, I am asking about angular templates. You can have type and auto completion in angular template, and I am asking if there is any way to make a pipe that would work for any types.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the problem. Maybe you can work with Angular's [keyvalue-pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)? You can iterate over objects and display the value of specific keys.

Comment: the problem is element is untyped in the template because angular can't know the type. I want to type it with a pipe, but without creating a pipe per tipe, but only a single pipe that type using a parameter